# How to build vb.net application so that database is easily connected when published?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, connection-string, publish

I've made VB.NET application in VS2010 that uses a 2007 Access database, called `MenuDB.mdb`. During development, everything was fine.

Now that I'm publishing it, I'm getting weird errors because for some reason the app isn't connecting to the database.

I install the application and run it but as soon as it opens it gives this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find file 
'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\OV86PXJA.K3R\8575R5AY.95Z\menu..tion_0d4fa454d69e8e6b_0001.0000_8340d263807cbb71\Data\MenuDB.accdb'.
```

I know the problem has to do with the way I'm relating the application to the database, but I don't know which way is right. In Solution Explorer I changed the Build Type of `MenuDB.accdb` to "Content" (earlier it was embedded resource". But it doesn't work either way. In my App.config I have the following connection string:

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MenuDB.accdb"
```

I want that when I deploy the application, the database should just sit in the application folder, wherever it gets installed. How can I do that?

### Edit

I don't mind deploying it in such a way that I need to paste the database somewhere myself on the target machine - as long as it works.

Comment: Did you verify that the database is being copied with the application and not excluded? I rarely develop with a database in the App_Data folder so alot of times i exclude anything that might be in the directory from the publishing/click-once solution.

Comment: Also, here is a MSDN question .... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winforms/thread/af9c7dc3-6a11-452d-9c93-cb006bcb8c16

Comment: I'm checking that thread. By the way this is my first VB.NET project - how can I verify it's being copied and not excluded? Are you referring to the Properties that come up with the .accdb file is clicked in Solution Explorer? (In my case, "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy if Newer".)

Comment: I don't mind deploying it in such a way that I need to paste the database somewhere myself on the target machine - as long as it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple users using the same or similar database, and dont have access to a SQL server (MySQL, MSSQL, or others), then co-locate the database at a central location (preferably network location) that all the users will have access to and change the connection string to accomidate the database location being on the network.

Just let it be known, Access can handle up to 10users when doing simple data retrieval/submission but if you ever have it open while others are accessing via data objects, then you may lock them out.

Comment: This is a small one-user desktop application. In Publish settings I tried "Application Files"> Include. But I'm still getting that error. How do we fix it? I don't require DSNs.

Comment: What method are you using to package up the application for installation?

Comment: @user961627 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/24ada8b9-7a27-4e86-a16a-d6a620d216a0/ Some Click-Once instructions.

Comment: Just what I get from the menu. Project > Publish. Then I choose offline, for CD etc. That's it.

Comment: Some of the program contains explicit code to the database, some is inherent. Wherever I explicitly make a connection using my own connection string, I can add in : Application.StartupPath and then just paste the database in the application folder. But how to add it in the App.config file, where "Application.StartupPath" isn't recognized?

Comment: do you have the ability to throw the database on a network location, or a location that is accessible off your computer?